# $http_cf_ipcountry and redirecting to different domains causes Too Many Redirects error

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I have this nginx configuration

```
# Map for country-based redirection to .ru
map $http_cf_ipcountry $redirect_to_ru {
    default 0;  # Default to not redirecting
    ~*(AM|AZ|BY|KZ|KG|RU|TJ|UZ) 1;  # Redirect if from specified countries
}

server {
    server_name www.website.com website.com;

    # Redirect to .ru if from specified countries
    if ($redirect_to_ru = "1") {
        return 301 https://www.website.ru$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    # ssl configs here
}

server {
    server_name www.website.ru website.ru;

    # FIXME, IT CAUSES TOO MANY REDIRECTS
    if ($redirect_to_ru = "0") {
        return 301 https://www.website.com$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    # ssl configs here
}
```

For users that come not from countries list it redirects ru->com (or doesn't redirect to com if user accesses [www.website.com](http://www.website.com))

But for users that come from the countries list it redirects com->ru domain many times, eventually causes Too Many redirects error.

In browser tools I can see that two requests, one comes from cloudflare, second one from nginx
See below
[image]
[image]

I can't understand what causes the redirection, and if `$http_cf_ipcountry` header is passed between calls.